# In OOAD, how should i represent the property that the entity is shared with multiple users with different permissions?

Tags: java, entity, ooad

I am developing a feature where i have an entity which represents a view. The entity holds the attributes as things what to display in view, name and other stuffs. These can be justified as attributes of the entity as it is tightly coupled with it. When it comes to the use case that the entity i.e the view is shared with multiple other users with different permission levels, since this not being tightly coupled with the entity should i place it inside the entity as a attribute or manage it separately from the entity.

I am new to OOAD and i tried to get the use case down and jot down the nouns as classes. Verbs as methods and stuff. So it would be better if you could throw some light on what should be done in such case could help me.

Use Case Diagramm

[image]

Class Diagramm
[image]

Comment: since you already have a lot of ideas in your mind, could you just share these with us? can you provide the **use case (UML)** and your **class diagramm (UML)** that we can provide help? Even if they might be not complete or flawed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinFrank i have added the UML diagrams by editing the question. Please refer to that. Currently i am keeping them separate and not associated as share can work just with the id of the view. It doesn't depend on the view object other than its mapping.

Comment: you should ask opinion based questions rather on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than on stackoverflow ;-) there you can gain deeper knowledge on design an architecture

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple permissions checks to be performed when working with views:

- is the user allowed to *open a (shared) view*
- is the user allowed to *edit a view*
- is the user allowed to *share a view*

so the permission is not only part of the *share a view to others* use case but used in (many) other use cases as well.

this assertion reveals, that the permission is needed as separate aspect of your application. so **yes, you should put your permission in a separate class**.

Code snippets:

**#1:** `public void editView(View view, User user, Share.Permission permission)`

vs.

**#2:** `public void editView(View view, User user, Permission permission)`

in example **#1** you have to know about

- view/user
- Share
- **and you have to know that Share has a Permission**

in example **#2** you simply have to know about

- view/user
- a permission